# Read-Only Button for List Item in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, list

I've got the following Sharepoint problem: I've created a Ribbon Button, which says "Read Only". When I am on a list, and check some items, I want to set those items to read only.
The ribbon button works great and when I am doing an alert or something, I get an answer. So this cannot be the problem. I did the following:

```
var listitem;
var roleAssgn;
var Assgn;
var selectedItems;

function readonly() {
    selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
    var currentListGuid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var currentWeb = context.get_web();
    var currentList = currentWeb.get_lists().getById(currentListGuid);

     for (k in selectedItems) {
        listitem = currentList.getItemById(selectedItems[k].id);
        context.load(listitem, 'RoleAssignments');
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.readonlyPerItem), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
    }
}

function readonlyPerItem(sender, args) {
    var k;
    var Assgn;
    var r;
  context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  roleAssgn = listitem.get_roleAssignments();

  for(r in roleAssgn){
        Assgn = roleAssgn[r];
        alert("1");
        context.load(Assgn, 'RoleDefinitionBindings');
        alert("2");
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.readonlyPerRoleA), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
    }
}

function readonlyPerRoleA(sender, args) {
    var bindings = Assgn.get_roleDefinitionBindings();
    var member = Assgn.get_member();
}

function failed(sender, args) {
        alert("FAIL");
}
```

This works great until it gets to the alerts. Alert-1 is working, but not Alert-2. The Debugger says: The object does not support the property "get_$h".
And that happens in the sp_runtime.js with:

> SP.DataRetrievalWithExpressionString.$1Q_0(a.get_$h(),d)

I dont really see a problem. Is this a bug or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I used another way to do this and wanted to let you know, how it worked for me. I used a JS in the Ribbon Menu to call another website, which is just an empty site. I added the parameters (listguid, siteurl and the itemid's comma-seperated).
Then that site just prints an "True" or "False". This response will be caught by my Ribbon JS and show some message if it worked or not. This is my Ribbon JS:

```
<CustomAction
    Id="ReadOnlyButton"
    RegistrationId="101"
    RegistrationType="List"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    Sequence="15"
    Rights="ManageLists"
    Title="Set Readonly">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.Documents.ReadOnly"
            Command="ReadOnly"
            Sequence="15"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/1031/images/formatmap16x16.png"
            Image16by16Left="-80"
            Image16by16Top="-128"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/1031/images/formatmap32x32.png"
            Image32by32Left="-160"
            Image32by32Top="-256"
            Description="Read Only"
            LabelText="Read Only" 
            TemplateAlias="o1"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
         Command="ReadOnly"
         CommandAction="javascript:
           var nid;
           function getItemIds()
           {
             var itemIds = '';
             var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
             var item;
             for(var i in items)
             {
               item = items[i];
               if(itemIds != '')
               {
                 itemIds = itemIds + ',';
               }
               itemIds = itemIds + item.id;               
             }
             return itemIds;
           }
           function handleReadyStateChange()
           {
             if (client.readyState == 4)
             {
               if (client.status == 200) 
               {
                 SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(nid);
                 if(client.responseText == 'True') {                  
                  nid = SP.UI.Status.addStatus('The Rights has been set successfully', '', true);
                  SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(nid, 'green');
                 } else {
                  nid = SP.UI.Status.addStatus('Error while setting Rights', '', true);
                  SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(nid, 'red');
                 }

                  window.setTimeout('SP.UI.Status.removeStatus(\'' + nid + '\')', 5000);
               }
             }
           }
           function invokeReadOnly()
           {
             var itemLength = 0;
             var params = 'itemids=' + getItemIds(); 
             for (var i=0;i&lt;params.length;i++) { if (',' == params.substr(i,1)) { itemLength++; } } 

             if(itemLength > 0) {
              nid = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Rights set for ' + (itemLength +1) + ' elements...', true);
             } else {
              nid = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Set Rights...', true);
             }

             var site='{SiteUrl}'; 
             var url = site + '/_layouts/ReadOnly.aspx?listId={ListId}';
             client = null;
             client = new XMLHttpRequest();
             client.onreadystatechange =  handleReadyStateChange;
             client.open('POST', url, true);         
             client.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
             client.setRequestHeader('Content-length', params.length);
             client.send(params);
           }      
           invokeReadOnly();"

      EnabledScript="javascript:
           function enableReadOnly()
           {
             var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
             return (items.length > 0);
           }
           enableReadOnly();"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

And this is my site behind it (ReadOnly.aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string itemidsAll = Page.Request["itemids"];
    string listId = Page.Request["listId"];
    bool set = true;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemidsAll))
    {
        string[] itemIds = itemidsAll.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int item = 0;

        SPSite _site = null;
        SPListItem spitem = null;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            _site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID);
        });
        using (SPWeb web = _site.OpenWeb())
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPList doclib = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.GetList(new Guid(listId), false);                

            foreach (string itemId in itemIds)
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(itemId, out item))
                {
                    spitem = doclib.GetItemById(item);
                    set &= SetItem(spitem, SPContext.Current, ref _site);
                }
            }

            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
        _site.Dispose();
    }

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(set.ToString());
    Response.End();  
}
```

The SetItem-Method is for setting the Rights. You can use your own stuff there :)